# While using scan and scroll in elastic search for 0.6M records , I'm getting the following response after 25K records

Tags: json, elasticsearch

```
{
   "_scroll_id":"$$28$$fDBHOsSTM1865ATfbaDWuw==$$xAwdTSkhdQTvpH-EKNOBnX3_fF4=c2NhbjswOzE7dG90YWxfaGl0czo2MTE5ODk7",
   "took":0,
   "timed_out":false,
   "_shards":{
      "total":0,
      "successful":0,
      "failed":0
   },
   "hits":{
      "total":611989,
      "max_score":0.0,
      "hits":[

      ]
   }
}
```

I have given the scroll refresh timing of 2m. Is this something to do with the scroll refresh time ?

Comment: Have you tried increasing the timing to 3, 4, 5 minutes? Also what's the scroll size? Can you show the first scroll/scan request?

Comment: The scroll size is 1000

Comment: What about my other questions? Help us help you!

Comment: {
"query":
  {"filtered":
   {
    "query":
     {
      "match_all":{}
     } 
                       }
               },
   "size":1000
}

Comment: I'm running with 5m now, it is still running.